# Injecting NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy in spring security 4.0.1

Tags: spring, spring-security, session-fixation

I am migrating an existing application using spring-security 3.1.3 to 4.0.1. In the current code I see NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy used as below

```
<sec:http>
..
<sec:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="ss"/>
</sec:http>
<bean id="ss" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy"/>
```

In our migrated code for 4.0.1 spring security, if i leave the same, it seems the SessionFixationProtectionStrategy is used. So i have switched off the protection using session-fixation-protection=none.

```
<sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
```

Q-1;
Here i am not clear what is the difference in using NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy vs that of switching off the protection as above.

Q-2;
If i still want to use NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy as in my current code, how to do that in 4.0.1?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused what your question is. You might consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Rob for taking a look at the question, As per your comment, i have re-phrased the question and added more details. Hope this explains!!